# UITableView frame modification with animation issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation

I have tried in so many ways to animate the frame modification of a UITableView, but when I shrink the tableview then the animation isn't smooth, first the cell content disappears, and only after that the frame is modified. As I saw this problem is present only in older OS, from iOS 3.2 this problem is fixed. Can anyone tell me a workaround, so that this animation works fine on older OS also?

Thank you

Comment: Sujanszky: this is a programming community, please post some code relevant to the question and perhaps you'll get help.  If you post a vague question, it is near impossible for people to help you if they don't understand your problem well enough.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I do think this is a valid issue, and I don't think his question is particularly vague.

Answer (score 0):

One option to fix the problem is take the screenshot of the current view.

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);     
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];  
    UIImage *viewImage                  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then hide our view and animate the screenshot image.
Then show our view with a timer function.